# how to get substrings javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like `var str = 'Foo faa {{Question14}} {{Question23}}'`. Now I want to get the substrings `{{Question14}}` and `{{Question23}}` by doing some operation on `str`. The digit part is variable in the `str`'s substrings. I need to replace these substrings with their respective ids. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is when [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) comes in handy.

```
var str = 'Foo faa {{Question14}} {{Question23}}'
var pattern = /(\{\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+\}\})/gi;
var matches = str.match(pattern);

console.log(matches[0]); //{{Question14}}
console.log(matches[1]); //{{Question23}}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of /gi? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

You can do It by this way:

```js
var
  str = 'Foo faa {{Question14}} {{Question23}}',
  arr = str.match(/{{Question[0-9]+}}/igm);

alert(arr[0]); // {{Question14}}
alert(arr[1]); // {{Question23}}
```

Replace matches with some IDs:

```
str.replace(/{{Question([0-9]+)}}/igm, "id=$1"); // "Foo faa id=14 id=23"
```

> When the regular expression contains groups (denoted by parentheses),
>   the matches of each group are available as $1 for the first group, $2
>   the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var str = 'Foo faa {{Question14}} {{Question23}}';
var replacements = {
   "{{Question14}}" : "Hello",
   "{{Question23}}" : "Hi",
};
   var output = str.replace(/{{\w+}}/g, function(match){ return replacements [match] });
   console.log(output);
```